# Syn read file and add line to function

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I'm trying to parse a file with syn, and add a line to the single function in it. However, it seems to not modify the file at all when writing it back out. I'm fairly sure that I don't understand fully proc-macro and am using it wrong.

In my `Cargo.toml` I define a `lib` and `bin` like so:

```ini
[lib]
name = "gen"
path = "src/gen.rs"
proc-macro = true

[[bin]]
name = "main"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

In my `gen.rs` file, I define a macro to take in the input, get the function and modify it like so:

```rust
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;

#[proc_macro]
pub fn gen(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let item = syn::parse(input.clone());

    match item {
        Ok(mut v) => {
            let fn_item = match &mut v {
                syn::Item::Fn(fn_item) => fn_item,
                _ => panic!("expected fn"),
            };
            fn_item.block.stmts.insert(
                0,
                syn::parse(quote!(println!("count me in");).into()).unwrap(),
            );

            use quote::ToTokens;
            return v.into_token_stream().into();
        }
        Err(error) => {
            println!("{:?}", error);
            return input;
        }
    };
}
```

Now in my `main.rs` file, I read the file, convert it to a `TokenStream`, and use my macro on it and write out the output to a file:

```rust
fn main() {
    if let Err(error) = try_main() {
        let _ = writeln!(io::stderr(), "{}", error);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}

fn try_main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let mut args = env::args_os();
    let _ = args.next(); // executable name

    let filepath = PathBuf::from("./src/file-to-parse.rs");

    let code = fs::read_to_string(&filepath).map_err(Error::ReadFile)?;
    let syntax = syn::parse_file(&code).map_err({
        |error| Error::ParseFile {
            error,
            filepath,
            source_code: code,
        }
    })?;

    let mut token_stream = TokenStream::new();
    syntax.to_tokens(&mut token_stream);
    let file_contents_updated = gen::gen!(&token_stream);

    std::fs::write("./src/file-updated.rs", file_contents_updated.to_string());

    Ok(())
}
```

Running this, my output file looks the same as the input. For reference, my input file looks like:

```rust
fn init() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: `syn::parse(quote!{})` -> [`syn::parse_quote!{}`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/macro.parse_quote.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've been misunderstood what proc macros do.

`gen::gen!(&token_stream)` will invoke `gen!()` **at compile time** with the literal tokens `&` `token_stream`. Since that doesn't look very much like a function, `syn` will fail to parse this, and your code will `println!("{:?}", error); return input;` (which by the way, is a bad idea for proc macro: parsing failure should abort compilation. Use `return err.into_compile_error().into()`). So it will return its input, meaning the output will be the same as the input.

You can use `syn` and `quote` for general purpose code generation, but you should not use proc macros for that - rather, use them as libraries. That is, `gen::gen(token_stream)` instead of `gen::gen!(&token_stream)`. You can also not mark it `proc_macro` and put it in the same crate.